# Can't get time value correctly in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns in excel that contain both the time and date in the format: yyyy/mm/dd h:mm:ss AM" (or PM)  I eventually have to send both the time and date to a method that creates outlook appointments in the calendar.  In a for each loop, this is how extract the date and time

```
startDate = CDate(Left(row.Columns(5), 10))
startTime = CDate(Right(row.Columns(5), 11))
```

Problem is when the time is 12:00 AM it turns into 0:0:0 in the excel sheet and when this value is sent to the outlook method, I get a "Run-time error: Type Mismatch: Cannot coerce parameter value.  Outlook cannot translate your string."

```
  With myapt
        .Subject = Subject
        .body = superString
        .Start = startDate & " " & startTime
```

Am I handling the date and time values correctly?  How do I resolve this issue?  Thank you

Comment: You can validate `If startTime = 0:0:0 Then` change the value to a value that Outlook can work with.

Comment: Does your Excel cell contain a date/time that is formatted as `"yyyy/mm/dd h:mm:ss"` (in which case you can probably just use `.Start = row.Columns(5).Value2`) or is it a string that looks like a date?  And what data type are your `startDate` and `StartTime` variables?

Comment: startDate and startTime are Date variables.  The cell is formatted as "yyyy/mm//dd h:mm:ss AM or PM"

Comment: If your cell contains a date/time (i.e. my current date/time is `43033.3582380787`) and that cell is formatted using a `"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss AM/PM"` cell format (i.e. my current date/time would be displayed as `2017/10/25 08:35:52 AM`), then just set `.Start` to the cell's `.Value2` property (which would be the number `43033.3582380787`).  But that will only work if the cell contains a **date/time** and is **formatted** as `"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss AM/PM"` so that it displays as `2017/10/25 08:35:52 AM` - it won't work if the cell contains **text** such as `2017/10/25 08:35:52 AM`.

Comment: Have you tried `DateValue(row.Columns("E")) + TimeValue(row.Columns("E"))`?

Comment: Thank you Patrick for reminding me.  Your solution works, I had implemented it before, but for some reason it stopped working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your Excel cell contains a date/time value and not just text that looks like a date and time (and from the comments that appears to be the case) you can use the following code:

```
With myapt
    .Subject = Subject
    .body = superString
    .Start = row.Columns(5).Value2
```

There is no point in creating a separate date variable and time variable, just to add them back together to get the number that was in the cell originally.